# Numpy: Is there a way to use np.argmax to search for consecutive values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to search a Numpy array for consecutive values and return their index?

For example, if we use argmax on an array to find the first instance of a single element:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
print(np.argmax(a == 1))
```

We get the result:

> 3

Is there a way to search this same array for the first instance of a pair?  E.g. I want to get the value `6` for the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
print(np.argmax(a == [1, 1]))
```

But instead it returns:

> 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small number of consecutive search pattern, we can simply slice and look for all matches and finally use *our-favourite* `argmax`.

Hence, for `2` consecutive search pattern, it would be -

```
In [6]: ((a[:-1]==1) & (a[1:]==1)).argmax()
Out[6]: 6
```

**Some explanation**

It's all about slicing, as we get two one-offsetted array slices. The one-offset comes because of the window-length of consecutive search being `2`. So, for a search window-length of `3`, we need to consider two-offsetted array slices and so on. Now, back to our simplistic two-consecutive window case, we have one-offsetted slices. We compare these against `1`, which gives us boolean arrays of matches. Then comes `AND-ing`, so that the entire window is covered. Finally jumps in our `argmax` to get the start of the first of those *islands*!

A break-down of the steps should help clarify further on the given sample -

```
In [24]: a
Out[24]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])

In [25]: a[:-1]
Out[25]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])

In [26]: a[:-1]==1
Out[26]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True])

In [27]: a[1:]==1
Out[27]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
        True,  True])

In [28]: (a[:-1]==1) & (a[1:]==1)
Out[28]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True,  True])

In [29]: ((a[:-1]==1) & (a[1:]==1)).argmax()
Out[29]: 6
```

#### Larger number of consecutive occurrences

For larger number of cons. occurrences, we can resort to something more *built-in* and use `np.convolve`, like so -

```
In [20]: W = 2 # window-length

In [21]: np.convolve(a,[1]*W,'same').argmax()-W//2
Out[21]: 6

In [22]: W = 3

In [23]: np.convolve(a,[1]*W,'same').argmax()-W//2
Out[23]: 9
```

Comment: Just to make sure I grok your answer: we logical AND two arrays.  In the first array, we are looking for locations where there is a single **prior** 1.  In the second array, we are looking for locations where there is a single **subsequent** 1.  Then we look at the AND'd array and find the first True.

Comment: Ah excellent, you edited your answer to provide some insight on ``n`` length consecutive searches before I had a chance to ask about it.  You're a quick one.

Comment: @WesH Added some explanation to clarify things.

Comment: The person who googles this question in the future will thank you.